# Вместо формы передать значение по ссылке

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Привет всем!)
Есть один вопрос, который мучает меня уже 2 дня(
Как передать значение ID по ссылке?
Пример:
есть таблица "files" в БД Mysql
поля

```
id
game
section
```

есть 2 стать к этой таблицы

1)

```
id - 1
game - 1
section - maps
```

2)

```
id - 2
game -2
section - maps
```

есть 2 ссылке

```
<a href="files.php?section=maps">Карты для Игры 1</a>
<a href="files.php?section=maps">Карты для Игры 2</a>
```

ВОПРОС- как вывести информацию с таблицы по ссылке не используя форму,и выводить так, чтобы при нажатии на 1-ю ссылку выводилась вся инфа, где поле game="1", а при нажатии на 2-ю ссылку выводилась все инфа, где поле game="2"? в браузере ссылка должна быть одним и тем же URL files.phpsection=game! Помогите решить этот вопрос)

Comment: кашу по полкам разложите

Comment: `<a href="files.php?section=maps&game=1">Карты для Игры 1</a>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Использовать форму и отправлять POST['id'].
Если требуется чтобы были текстовые ссылки то используйте функцию onclick для вызова отправки формы.

```
<form action="files.php?section=maps" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
<font onclick="submit()">Карты для Игры 1</font>
</form>
<form action="files.php?section=maps" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
<font onclick="submit()">Карты для Игры 2</font>
</form>
```

Comment: не используя форму (вы не внимательно прочитали вопрос!)

Comment: Тогда попробуйте позаморачиваться с редиректом и сесиями.
Отправляя изначально по ссылке files.php?section=maps&id=1, перехватывать наличие $_GET['id'] записывать её в сессию, делать редирект header("Location: http://site.ru/files.php?section=maps"); и там уже брать $_SESSION['id'] и делать выборку из базы.
Получится конечно почёсывание за правым ухом левой пяткой, но работать будет :-). Главное не забывайте после получения значения $_SESSION['id'] обнулять эту переменную чтобы не было ложных срабатываний.

Comment: а если я буду загружать ссылки через форму, много ли я времени потеряю чем просто загружать ссылки???

Comment: немного. Мой первый ответ самый оптимальный в Вашем случае и по времени и по чистоте кода.